# Is a black hole an atom (quanta)?

Tags: philosophy-of-science

Understandably black holes evaporate, so we don't get the permanent things Democritus posited, but if indivisibility is the core feature required of an atom or quanta, both in classical thought and now, how is a black hole not one of the above?

Comment: You need to define what you mean by atom or quanta, otherwise the answer to this question isn't clear. If you are specifically talking about the atoms that Democritus talked about then quanta are red herrings because it sounds like you're conflating what he thought with what we understand today. [The singularity of a black hole](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/spacetime-singularities/) is not a particle, it is literally a point in spacetime, so conflating it with Democritus' atoms isn't cogent. It also [is not the only part of a black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_horizon).

Comment: Mostly this is about the indivisibility aspect (which seems core to all definition of atom). And not the singularity, the event horizon (since no volume within the horizon can 'split' from the black hole)

Comment: No, atoms are divisible, atoms are made out of protons, neutrons, and electrons, and those with the exception of an electron are divisible as well. This is why you need to be clear with your definitions and what you're talking about. If you are strictly talking about Democritus and his definitions and his views then you need to make that clear, because talking about modern physics while using his words is misleading because he did not know anything about atoms, subatomic particles, or black holes.

Comment: What is usually called "black hole" is the region under the event horizon, and that is certainly "divisible". As for the singularity, it is considered an unphysical artifact of mathematics. Presumably, GR breaks down already near the event horizon, but it most certainly breaks down around the singularity, the same goes for the [Big Bang singularity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initial_singularity).

Comment: Atoms were originally taken to be also unalterable; since the mass and charge of a black hole does change they won't count as such; I think some physicists have been taken by the analogy.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is unclear physics.

Answer (score 3):

Black holes are not atomic in the sense that two of them they will happily merge given the chance. The fact that this process is irreversible doesn't change the fact that the resulting black hole is composed of the two initial black holes.

Comment: I am terrified to ask, but where did all the mass go?  Do they still have mass/gravity?  These points must be very dense, does the big point swallow the little point, or will someone tell me these points have no mass!?